# Sequence of iid entered random variables with finite variance prove that for any $\gamma>1 / 2$, $\sum_{i \geq 1} \xi_i / i^\gamma$ converges a.s.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I'm trying to teach my self the first 10 chapters of: "Leonid Koralov, Yakov G. Sinai - Theory of probability and random processes" out of interest.
The following, in my opinion, also uses a "general" trick to prove almost sure convergence, which I also would like to better understand.

**Problem:**
Let $\xi_1, \xi_2, \ldots$ be a sequence of independent identically distributed random variables for which $\mathrm{E} \xi_i=0$ and $\mathrm{E} \xi_i^2=V<\infty$. Prove that for any $\gamma>1 / 2$, the series $\sum_{i \geq 1} \xi_i / i^\gamma$ converges almost surely.

First of all, I would like to note that as I understand converges almost surely, that is in probability. Meaning that for example

$P\left(\sup_{I \geq 1}\left|S_{n+i}-S_n\right|>\varepsilon\right) \rightarrow 0$, as $ n \rightarrow \infty$, where
$S_n:=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\xi_i}{i^\gamma}$.

I think, we can note that,
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
& S_n:=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\xi_i}{i^\gamma}=\frac{\xi_1}{1^\gamma}+\frac{\xi_2}{2^\gamma}+\frac{\xi_3}{3^\gamma}+\cdots+\frac{\xi_n}{n^\gamma} \\
& =\frac{\xi_1}{1^\gamma}+\frac{\xi_1}{2^\gamma}+\frac{\xi_1}{3^\gamma}+\cdots+\frac{\xi_1}{n^\gamma}=\xi_1\left(\frac{1}{1^\gamma}+\frac{1}{2^\gamma}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n^\gamma}\right) \\
& =\xi_1 \sum_{i=1}^n 1 / i^\gamma \\
&
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

and thus

$P\left(\sup_{i=1}\left|S_{n+i}-S_n\right|>\varepsilon\right)=\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty}\left(P\left(\max_{1 \leq i, N}\left|S_{n+i}-S_n\right| \geq \varepsilon\right)\right) \leq_{Kolmogorov} \left(\xi_1 \sum_{i=n+1}^{\infty} 1 / i \gamma\right) / \varepsilon^2$

where the right-hand side can be made arbitrarily small by choosing $n$ large enough.

I feel like I'm close, but that it isn't quite enough, since I'm not using $\gamma>1/2$ and maybe I should use Borel-Cantelli Lemma?

Help to this question (and also improving StackExchange questions in general) is highly appreciated. Thank you.

**Edit: Solution** use Three Series Theorem by Kolmogorov, with c = 1, as stated in comments.

Comment: Are you allowed to use/have you heard of the Kolmogorov Three Series Theorem?

Comment: Yes, actually where I found inspiration for my proof. In the book it is stated as: Theorem 7.8. (Three Series Theorem) Let $\xi_i$ be a sequence of independent random variables. If for some $c>0$ each of the three series
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \mathrm{E} \xi_i^c, \quad \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \operatorname{Var}\left(\xi_i^c\right), \quad \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \mathrm{P}\left(\left|\xi_i\right| \geq c\right)
\end{align*}
converges, then the series $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \xi_i$ converges almost surely.

Comment: Thank you! I got it. Quite trivial actually, with that three series theorem :)

Comment: Sorry! Just saw you comment! I added some hints below, but looks like you already got it. Nice!